# Ubuntu set default outgoing ipv6 address

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ip, ipv6, netplan

On my ubuntu server I configured multiple ipv6 addresses as following with netplan:

```
network:
version: 2
renderer: networkd
ethernets:
    eth0:
        addresses:
        - xx.xx.xx.xx/22
        - xxxx:xxxx:xx:xx::/64
        - xxxx:xxxx:xx:xx::1/64
        - xxxx:xxxx:xx:xx::2/64
        gateway4: xx.xx.xx.1
        gateway6: fe80::1
        match:
            macaddress: ab:cd:ef:ab:cd:ef
        nameservers:
            addresses:
            - 127.0.0.1
            - ::1
            - xx.xx.xx.xx
            - xx:xx:xx::xxxx
```

For outgoing ipv6 connection the server always uses the address `xxxx:xxxx:xx:xx::2/64` instead of `xxxx:xxxx:xx:xx::/64`.

How can I permanently set `xxxx:xxxx:xx:xx::/64` as default outgoing ip address?

Comment: There is actually an RFC covering the address selection (not that Linux necessarily follows the RFCs). It is _[RFC 6724, Default Address Selection for Internet Protocol Version 6 (IPv6)](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6724)_.

Comment: I'm confused about what you are asking. For example, if a remote device want to create a TCP connection with this server, then the server must use the IP address to which the remote host sent the connection request. For TCP, you cannot have a connection that uses one IP address for inbound traffic, and a different IP address for outbound traffic. The TCP connection depends on those being the same address, else a connection will never be formed.

Comment: You should avoid using the first address in an IPv6 /64 for a host (where the host part is all zeroes). This is the subnet-router anycast address, and should be assigned to the subnet's routers, or not assigned at all.

Answer (score 0):

Set `lifetime: 0` on the non preferred addresses. From `man netplan(5)`:

> lifetime (scalar) – since 0.100
>
> Default:  forever.   This  can be forever or 0 and corresponds
> to the PreferredLifetime  option  in  systemd-networkd’s
> Address section.  Currently supported on the networkd backend only.

Updating your example to include this:

```
network:
    version: 2
    renderer: networkd
    ethernets:
        eth0:
            addresses:
            - xx.xx.xx.xx/22
                lifetime: 0
            - xxxx:xxxx:xx:xx::/64
            - xxxx:xxxx:xx:xx::1/64
                lifetime: 0
            - xxxx:xxxx:xx:xx::2/64
                lifetime: 0
            gateway4: xx.xx.xx.1
            gateway6: fe80::1
            match:
                macaddress: ab:cd:ef:ab:cd:ef
            nameservers:
                addresses:
                - 127.0.0.1
                - ::1
                - xx.xx.xx.xx
                - xx:xx:xx::xxxx
```